# set max item in listbox in windows phone 8.1

Tags: listbox, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm Stuck here to limit my items in my listbox in Windows PHone 8.1,
is there any way to limit all items? for example I want only 4 items inside the listbox?
thank you :)

```
ListBox Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxobj" SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="350" >
                        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="28" Foreground="White"  Text="{Binding PrayerTitle }"/>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text=">" FontSize="28"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PhoneTxt"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PrayerContent }" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <!--<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CreateddateTxt" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />-->
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: You have to impose that constraint on the binded source in your viewmodel.

Comment: @ChiragShah hello brother, thanks for the help, yaap. indeed, why this thought never come before hahaha. thanks a lot. Im thinking to much for this

Comment: @GifttraPratama Now you know the answer :) :-)